# Getting WHERE statement to work in v.generalize?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, sql, generalization

I have a shape (its topology is terrible but I don't think it's the problem).  I'm trying to simplify it to reduced it's size using `v.generalise`.  I succeeded at reducing the whole shape but I actually want to do a two steps simplification:

1. simplifying all the shape with threshold 0.0001 first,
2. simplifying all the polygons with `urban=0` further more with threshold 0.0003

The problem is that my second `v.generalize` call simplifies everything, like if the `WHERE` call wasn't working.

For this question, we will just focus on the point 2, so here what I do:

A subset of my data can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/g5x2aw5pmdumqtn/AABfT1aqjdiKnru1cOC_tCp3a?dl=0).

And here is some visualization of what I did:

My shape initially:

[image]

My `v.generalize` call:

[image]

The result (below) show the blue line the new polygons border which where simplified even if they were not in `urban=0`.

[image]

Just like if the `WHERE` statement was ignore.  I don't see any error in the log specific to that SQL statement.  The actual call to GRASS built by QGIS is:

```
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>v.generalize input=vector_5be4482a0b8e72 type="line,boundary,area" where="urban=0" method="douglas" threshold=0.0003 look_ahead=7 reduction=50 slide=0.5 angle_thresh=3 degree_thresh=0 closeness_thresh=0 betweeness_thresh=0 alpha=1 beta=1 iterations=1 -l output=output96039149be394bdaa48a3ba7d8b849f7 error=error96039149be394bdaa48a3ba7d8b849f7 --overwrite
```

I've try multiple `WHERE` statement (`urban="0"`, `urban<1`, etc) to try to match the `v.generalise` [tutorial](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/V.generalize_tutorial#Gereneral_Parameters) but still no luck.  I also tried to do it directly in GRASS bypassing QGIS and the problem persist meaning is not a QGIS problem more than a GRASS problem.

In this example, the `urban` field is a real number.

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify the data type of the `urban` field. I note that you did not list the valid SQL varchar delimiter -- single-quote -- in your examples (`urban = '0'`)

Comment: Just did.  In this case it's real, but I got other ones in my different tests (character, interger64, etc.).  I also tried more complex queries (`SUBSTR(FSALDU,2,1)==’0’`, `SUBSTRING(FSALDU,2,1)=’0’`, etc.)

Comment: I reproduced the issue on GRASS with your layer, tried a few things but didn't work. QGis seems out of cause yes, did you try with other layers/settings or is it definitely a GRASS issue ?

Comment: Yes, I tried it with another shape and I get the same problem (example shape from R `library(sf)` could be created in R with: `st_read(system.file("gpkg/nc.gpkg", package="sf"), quiet = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(CNTY = as.numeric(CNTY_<median(CNTY_))) %>% 
  select(CNTY) %>% 
  st_transform(st_crs(2264)) %>% 
  st_write("d:/temp/NC_test.shp")`.  With a threshold of 10000 and a WHERE of `CNTY<1` you get the same behaviour.  Guess I should open an issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the use of the  `cat` and `WHERE` options from `v.generalize` requires the `layer=1` option set as well.  As of right now (nov 2018), QGIS default value for `layer` is set to `-1` and doesn't allow to be change making QGIS currently useless for using `v.generalize` with the `WHERE` option.  Use GRASS directly instead.

The [tutorial](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/V.generalize_tutorial#Gereneral_Parameters) now give good example on how to use the `WHERE` statement.

Further details on this problem can be obtained [here](https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/ticket/3694).